# Performance difference between RPC and normal linked server select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a linked server named `[ls1]`.
what is performance difference between these two types of select:

```
DECLARE @Temp NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'USE Test SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table_1] AS [t]'
EXEC (@Temp) AT [ls1]
```

and this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM [ls1].[Test].[dbo].[Table_1]
```

and does it make difference if server hardware become stronger, weaker or equal to client?
my test gives me different execute time on each time I run queries. sometimes query 1 is faster but some times server is faster. why does it happens?

Comment: I'm fairly positive it's all just due to the network and that's why the executions vary even on the same query. I don't think there's big of a difference between the two, I'd prefer the second though as it is "strongly typed".

Comment: Thank you @MK_. Seems that nobody else is going to answer. so your answer must be correct and should have a green check.

Comment: There's another actual answer now so you decide, if you want me to turn my comment into a bigger answer let me know.

Comment: @MK_ you answered first and deserve that big green check.

Comment: Okay than, thanks. I added it as an answer. Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly positive the execution times difference is just due to the network and that's why the executions vary even on the same query.

I don't think there's big of a difference between the two, I'd prefer the second though as it is "strongly typed". It's what I've always been using and no problems so far (except for network issues or latency sometimes - but that simply happens when dealing with remote server).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding performance it should be the same (the 2nd might be already compiled), however using the 2nd method will make the engine validate the table when parsing the script. So these will behave different, if both statements are on the same batch.

Check at runtime (execution error):

```
-- Divide by zero error encountered.
SELECT
    1/0

-- Could not find server 'LinkedServer' in sys.servers.
DECLARE @Temp NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'USE DataBaseName SELECT T.SomeColumn FROM SchemaName.TableName AS T'
EXEC (@Temp) AT [LinkedServer]
```

Check first (parse/compile error):

```
-- Could not find server 'LinkedServer' in sys.servers.
SELECT
    1/0

SELECT
    T.SomeColumn
FROM
    [LinkedServer].DataBaseName.SchemaName.TableName AS T
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to reply me